# Ensure rest of Spring application runs even when one bean has errors during runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Right now I am working on a Spring application that contains multiple components, including one RabbitMQ component.

The initialization of the RabbitMQ connection is through configuration beans that automatically become alive when the application starts.

Below is my RabbitMQ configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:message.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:rabbitmq.properties")
})
@EnableRabbit
public class MessageConfiguration {

    private static final String MESSAGE_HOST_PROPERTY = "message.host";

    private static final String FACTORY_USERNAME_PROPERTY = "rabbitmq.username";
    private static final String FACTORY_PASSWORD_PROPERTY = "rabbitmq.password";


    private Environment environment;



    @Autowired
    public MessageConfiguration(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }


    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate publishTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate result = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        return result;
    }


    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(environment.getProperty(MESSAGE_HOST_PROPERTY));
        connectionFactory.setUsername(environment.getProperty(FACTORY_USERNAME_PROPERTY));
        connectionFactory.setPassword(environment.getProperty(FACTORY_PASSWORD_PROPERTY));
        return connectionFactory;
    }
}
```

In the Bean connectionFactory, if I supply the wrong username and password, my application would run into authentication errors:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.internalRabbitListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIllegalStateException: Fatal exception on listener startup
    Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIllegalStateException: Fatal exception on listener startup
    Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.FatalListenerStartupException: Authentication failure
    Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpAuthenticationException: com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
```

At the same time, the rest of my application that doesn't relate to RabbitMQ would not run.

Is there a way to contain the RabbitMQ bean error just to itself and not to all other components so the rest of the application can run?

Comment: You can try to divide your contexts so that rabbitMQ context will be in its own. I don't sure about implementation though

Comment: Is this an environment problem by chance? Is it perhaps that you don't have RabbitMQ set up in specific environments and you still want the application to be able to run? I would assume that in, say, production, you'd always expect it to be present and would want to fail if it was not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication errors are considered fatal.

For transient errors (such as the broker not running), the application will start and attempt to reconnect.

> FatalListenerStartupException

You don't show your listener configuration, but you can configure the listener containers to not start automatically, via the `autoStartup` property. If false, the context will always load ok.

You can then try to `start()` the container within your code and catch exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to let the listeners start automatically, pause when encountering authentication error while letting the rest of the application run, and resume when correct credentials are supplied?

Comment: No; you need to manage the container lifecycle yourself to get the functionality you want - it's rather unusual to have credential configuration change dynamically while an application is running.